# Socket.io how to store more information that is common to room's users?

Tags: socket.io

I'm developing a game using socket.io & nodejs. Two players get a set of boxes, which is an array, when they're done with what they had and I'm keeping record of how many set is requested.

The thing is I want to send request count to both players in the room whenever a request has been made. I can hold this info in database but that would be very inefficient, it's a real-time multiplayer game.

Because I have to emit both player's box count to the room, I thought having their box count in the room array would help but couldn't figure out. Just to give an idea:

In socket.io rooms hold info as this:

```
{ someUniqueSocketId : true, someAnotherSocketId : true}
```

I want it to hold like this:

```
{someUniqueSocketId : {setCountOfThisPlayer : true} ,
 someAnotherSocketId : {setCountOfThatPlayer : true}}
```

Or maybe there is a better way to hold such an info.

EDIT:

When a player sends a startGame signal, this works:

```
function startGame(){
    this.setCount = 0;
    io.to(matchRoom).emit('allSets', allSets);
};
```

allSets is an array of all boxes. It **holds box count as property of the socket by this.setCount.** But I cannot access other player's properties, so this doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show more code?  It's hard to suggest a good solution without seeing more of what you have now.  Where are you storing such info as player name right now?  What does your emit code look like?

Answer (score 1):

Without storing it on the DB you could store it in a variable on the server. Not recommended becasue it eats mem and won't scale. Maybe you can tap into local storage of each user and manage it that way. It'd require a bit of coding but a few functions could handle that client side and you could have an additional function to update the server/players connected to the socket.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to add a bit more structure to your server to track Players and Rooms outside of socket.io functionality.

Here's a quick example of how you might structure a simple room setup.
I kept it quite simple and indulged in some structural shortcuts, so it probably wouldn't pass a best practices review.

```
var players = {};
var rooms = {};
rooms['randomId236512'] = {// add an example starter room
    id: 'randomId236512',
    name: 'Happy Box House Room',
    players: [],
    started: false,
    setCount: 0
};

function findOpenRoom() {
    //here you would search through the list of games waiting for players
    //if no rooms, make one, add it to the list, then return it
    return rooms[0];
}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

var newPlayer = {//A better pratice would be create a "class" or new function for the Player object
    name: 'Mr. Jones',
    color: 'blue',
    currentRoom: null,
    requestedSets: [],//or could just be NumRequestedSets
    //Whatever additional game related data could go here
    //Alternately, if the data is specific to the whole game, put it on the room itself
};
players[socket.id] = newPlayer;//Adding this to the players dictionary will let us find the player object again via their socket id

var openRoom = findOpenRoom();
newPlayer.currentRoom = openRoom; //Now the player object has a reference to the game room it's in
openRoom.players.push(newPlayer);
socket.join(openRoom.id);//This will create a new socket.io channel to make it easy to emit to a single room

socket.on('startGame', function (socketId, msg) {
    var myRoom = players[socketId].currentRoom;
    myRoom.started = true;
    myRoom.setCount = 0;//Ensure 0 at start
    //Broadcast the startGame message here,  see below for building gamestate
});

socket.on('requestSet', function (socketId, msg) {

    sendSetOfBoxes(players[socketId]);//Respond to the message here, update the requested set number or whatever

    var gameState = {
        playerData: []
    };
    var myRoom = players[socketId].currentRoom;
    for (var i = 0; i < myRoom.players.length; i++) {
        //Loop over the players, and build a list of players and their history of requested sets
        gameState.playerData.push({
            name: myRoom.players[i].name,
            requestedSetHistory: myRoom.player[i].requestedSets
        })
    }
    socket.broadcast.to(myRoom.id).emit('setWasRequested', gameState);
});
function sendSetOfBoxes(player) {
    //do your sending of boxes here
}
});
```